# Как задать многострочный комментраий в j2 шаблоне ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.

# Global configuration
#


# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
```

Как закомментировать несколько строк чтобы это не уехало в конфиг на сервере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Комментарии в jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#comments): `{# ... #}`

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.

# Global configuration
#


{# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#}
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
```

Теперь описание ServerRoot в результирующий файл не попадет.